# Updating prices based on options

Tags: javascript, html

So I am making this billing system where a user is able to configure a VPS. As seen in websites like Dell, the price of the server updates as you choose a specific option. I don't want the user to have to press a button "Refresh" every time they want to see the price of the new VPS. I have no idea how to do this, I tried to do some research and the only thing I found that was remotely close to this was things like Comet. I'm guessing that JavaScript should detect the change and change the overall price. Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you wanna use JavaScript to achieve this.

```
<form action="">
    <ul>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="1"> One</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="2"> Two</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="3"> Three</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="4"> Four</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="5"> Five</label></li>
    </ul>
</form>
<p>Your total cost is <span>0</span> $.</p>
```

And a magic of JavaScript...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").click(function(){
        val = 0;
        $("input:checked").each(function(){
            val += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $("span").text(val);
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/q3XbZ/

Comment: Is there any way to do the same thing with a dropdown menu too?

Comment: @Starfire1337 Yes possible!